# Algorithmic problem solution without using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, dictionary

I am trying to solve the next case without using a for loop... Meaning trying to use only filter, reduce, map or combination of them.

I got an array of Objects:

```js
const items = 
  [ { label: 1, count: 22, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 2, count: 10, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 3, count:  3, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 4, count:  1, isRefined: false } 
  ]
 
const products = 
  [ { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 2 } , { LocationType: 3 } ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 3 }                       ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 3 } , { LocationType: 4 } ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 }                                             ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 2 } , { LocationType: 3 } ]} 
  ]
```

The case is next:

I need to overwrite each item's inner Object count key with the value of corresponding products with the Objects in which the Locations objects contain the matching Location Type to the items object label...

For example, the output here should be

```js
const output = 
  [ { label: 1, count: 5, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 2, count: 2, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 3, count: 4, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 4, count: 1, isRefined: false } 
  ]
```

I am totally stuck on trying to come to a solution without using a for loop or any kind of for loop, help would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: By `for` loop, do you mean specifically `for (let i = 0; i < someNum; i++)`, or are you referring to any form of iteration? What about `.map()` or `.forEach()` on an arrray?

Comment: Shouldn't `label: 3` have a `count` of `4` instead of `3`? Please verify your examples beforehand

Comment: 'Array(#)` is not valid. As Ibrahim recommended , we need valid staring points before we can really help.

Comment: Your instructor is most likely attempting to point you to the use of `reduce` or `map`.

Comment: Sorry i edited the mistakes.

By for loop i mean specifically ``for (let i = 0; i < someNum; i++)```, forEach, forOf.

Yes he did say that the preferable way would be to use reduce, map or filter.

Comment: Please check my answer, no `for`/`forEach`/`forOf` used, only `map` and `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, and elegant.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to [@plichard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard) for suggesting in the comments below to use the `some()` method and object destructuring in the `filter` callback. It's really neat that way !

```
const output = items.map(item => {
  const matches = (location) => location.LocationType == item.label;
  const filtered = products.filter(({ Locations }) => Locations.some(matches));
  return { ...item, count: filtered.length };
});
```

Comment: `some()` seems more appropriate than coercing a boolean out of filter. `products.filter(({ Locations }) => Locations.some(matches));`

Comment: @pilchard Haven't thought about this one, that's even better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the counts (the number of times each location type appears in the `products` array), preferably as an object where the keys are the location types and the values are the counts. For that a simple `reduce`/`forEach` will do the job like so:

```
let counts = products.reduce((counts, locs) => {
  locs.Locations.forEach(loc =>
    counts[loc.LocationType] = (counts[loc.LocationType] || 0) + 1
  );
  return counts;
}, {});
```

Then simply `map` the `items` array into a new array where you shallow-copy the objects using a spread syntax and update the `count` property using the `counts` object calculated earlier:

```
const newItems = items.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  count: counts[item.label] || 0
}));
```

And if you want to alter the original objects themselves instead, then a simple `forEach` will suffice:

```
items.forEach(item => item.count = counts[item.label] || 0);
```

The  `|| 0` part is a fallback value in case the item doesn't have any location types in the `products` array, in which case `counts[item.label]` will be `undefined` and `0` will be used instead. This is called short-circuit evaluation.

**Demo:**

```js
const items = [{label: 1, count: 22, isRefined: false}, {label: 2, count: 10, isRefined: false}, {label: 3, count: 3, isRefined: false},{label: 4, count: 1, isRefined: false}];

const products = [{Locations:[{LocationType:1},{LocationType:2},{LocationType:3}]},{Locations:[{LocationType:1},{LocationType:3}]},{Locations:[{LocationType:1},{LocationType:3},{LocationType:4}]},{Locations:[{LocationType:1}]},{Locations:[{LocationType:1},{LocationType:2},{LocationType:3}]}];



let counts = products.reduce((counts, locs) => {
  locs.Locations.forEach(loc =>
    counts[loc.LocationType] = (counts[loc.LocationType] || 0) + 1
  );
  return counts;
}, {});

const newItems = items.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  count: counts[item.label] || 0
}));

console.log(newItems);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm, ill check with him if forEach is acceptable. :)

Comment: @BranislavBrnjoš You're welcome! I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

In case forEach is not an option, here is another solution that uses map, reduce and filter.

```
const result = items.map(d => {
    const locationCount = products.reduce((count, p) => count + p.Locations.filter(l => l.LocationType == d.label).length, 0);
    let item = Object.assign({}, d);
    item.count = locationCount;
    return item;
 })
```

For example:

```js
const items = 
  [ { label: 1, count: 22, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 2, count: 10, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 3, count:  3, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 4, count:  1, isRefined: false } 
  ] 
const products = 
  [ { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 2 } , { LocationType: 3 } ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 3 }                       ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 3 } , { LocationType: 4 } ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 }                                             ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 2 } , { LocationType: 3 } ]} 
  ] 

const result = items.map(d => {
    const locationCount = products.reduce((count, p) => count + p.Locations.filter(l => l.LocationType == d.label).length, 0);
    let item = Object.assign({}, d);
    item.count = locationCount;
    return item;
})

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your solution botch the integrity of `items` (their count values are modified)

Comment: @MisterJojo fixed, thanks for pointing out

Comment: one line : `return Object.assign({}, d, {count: locationCount})`

Answer (score 0):

my way...

```js
const countP = v => products.filter(p=>p.Locations.some(x=>x.LocationType===v)).length

const output = items.map(el=>({...el, count: countP(el.label)}))
```

proof:

```js
const items = 
  [ { label: 1, count: 22, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 2, count: 10, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 3, count:  3, isRefined: false } 
  , { label: 4, count:  1, isRefined: false } 
  ] 

const products = 
  [ { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 2 } , { LocationType: 3 } ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 3 }                       ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 3 } , { LocationType: 4 } ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 }                                             ]} 
  , { Locations: [{ LocationType: 1 } , { LocationType: 2 } , { LocationType: 3 } ]} 
  ] 

const countP = v => products.filter(p=>p.Locations.some(x=>x.LocationType===v)).length

const output = items.map(el=>({...el, count: countP(el.label)}))  
console.log( output )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console-row         { background-color: #87f1f1; }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
```